# How to skip reading rows with prefix in a data file using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a data file in which columns are separated with one or more spaces consistently. Header rows that are prefixed with a '#' exist here and then. How do I read the file with

> read_csv('filename.csv')

while omitting the header rows only.
The header rows have 10 columns while other data rows have 9 columns.
A portion of the data file looks like:

```
#POM00008579 1948 01 11 15 9999    6 ncdc6310           387670   -91330
21 -9999 102100B  106   170B  690 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999 100000   182B  150B  700 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  85000  1529B   40B  600 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  70000  3083B  -30B  100 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  50000  5671B -200B  100 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  40000  7240B -360B  100 -9999 -9999 -9999
#POM00008579 1948 01 12 03 9999    5 ncdc6310           387670   -91330
21 -9999 102900B  106   110B  790 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999 100000   244B  110B  700 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  85000  1573B   10B  700 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  70000  3136B  -10B  200 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  50000  5739B -180B  300 -9999 -9999 -9999
#POM00008579 1948 01 13 03 9999    5 ncdc6310           387670   -91330
21 -9999 103200B  106   100B  830 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999 100000   267B  100B  800 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  85000  1614B   80B  300 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  70000  3191B   10B  200 -9999 -9999 -9999
10 -9999  50000  5809B -180B  300 -9999 -9999 -9999
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `comment="#"`

**Ex:**

```
pandas.read_csv('filename.csv', comment='#')
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday :)